# Creating shapefile of satellite image footprints?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, erdas-imagine

I'm looking for a tool or a workflow to compute satellite image footprints, for a large number of images across directories, and produce a shapefile. Ideal work flow would be:

- fire up tool
- point to a directory and provide file mask
- the tool browses directory and sub-directories and compute footprints
- the tool produces a shapefile with a polygon for each footprint and pre-selected attributes

It would preferably be Esri or ERDAS based, but not necessarily.

Comment: For non-arc, you can use gdaltindex.  You can definitely run this on a script to browse sub-directories.  http://www.gdal.org/gdaltindex.html

Comment: I agree with @maning - gdaltindex will do exactly what you're after.

Comment: @maning I tried to use `gdaltindex` but unfortunately this tool creates bounding box instead of footprint. According to this definitions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/269689/35561

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In arcgis10 when you add images to a [raster mosaic dataset](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_what_s_new_in_ArcGIS_10/00qp0000000p000000/) there are options to create footprints and metadata.

Comment: +1 My thoughts exactly. Last step is to export the Footprints table of the Mosaic Dataset.

Answer (score 0):

How about this Creating Raster Index for ArcGIS ?

Here is the link you can go and see if this is what you need or not...

http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15732

I tried this and works very well..but I am not sure if this is what you need.

Take care.

Comment: Unfortunately this program does not generate the exact footprints where valid data are, but rather bounding boxes.