# Calculating Image boundary / footprint of satellite images using open source tools?

Tags: gdal, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, footprint

I need to create the polygon outlines of several single layer raster images, not the extent/bounding box, but the area without the nodata values, as shown here: [Creating shapefile showing footprints of Rasters?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26893/how-do-i-create-a-shapefile-showing-footprints-of-rasters).

In the answer to the question above, the *Image Boundary plugin* was mentioned, however, I don't find it in the QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa, running on Ubuntu.

Is the tool still available?

If not, is there a way to do this using opensource tools, either gdal, R, QGIS, GRASS, or similar, not with ArcMap?

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9074/creating-shapefile-of-satellite-image-footprints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the old repository where have plugins out in Official Repository.

http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed

The image boundary plugin have option for calculate valid pixel, but, the image need be the full scene, how CBERS or Landsat, where this process calculate the first 4 corners. The image need have nodata with ZERO value for area without imaging(scanned by satellite sensor).

Author of Image Boundary

Comment: Hi @lmotta, thanks for for the repository link. The images I'm working on at the moment are all SAR images, with NA values (or -3.4e+38 according to the value tool in QGIS). If one could add the nodata value manually in the tool, instead of having ZERO as the only option, it would be great, otherwise, I might first run a script in R to give my NA values new values of zero. It's a great tool though, thanks!

Comment: Is there a new repository for Image Boundary? The link you provide is 404. Maybe the following?: https://github.com/lmotta/imagefootprint_plugin

Comment: Is there anywhere that we can find documentation for Image Boundary?

Answer (score 15):

I finally found a way to do this:

**step 1:**
`gdalwarp -dstnodata 0 -dstalpha -of GTiff foo1 foo2`

This does two important things: it sets the destination *No Data* (outside border) values to 0, and it creates an alpha band.

**step 2:**
`gdal_polygonize.py foo2 -b 2 -f "ESRI Shapefile" foo3`

The second step uses the alpha band (band 2), created in step 1, and creates a shapefile from that band.

This can then easily be scripted in a bash script, if you have many images, to create exact outlines for.

Comment: Brilliant, this solution does not rely on any plugins or software. Creating raster footprints that are sensitive to NoData is one of those GIS tasks that is not as straightforward as it feels like it should be.

Comment: When I use this method I end up with a shapefile full of polygons which I assume represent different colors grouped together. How can I avoid this and end up with just a few polygons represent yes-data??

Comment: @Loonuh Probably the reason the above didn't work for you is the `-b 2` which says use 2nd band and you had a multiband image. The number should be changed to match the Alpha band created in step 1. Also see the related https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/408628/108, which shows an example of scaling all data values into a single group.

Answer (score 6):

*Image Boundary plugin* did not work for me either, therefore I used the same approach with GDAL. Nevertheless it only worked for me after changing the first step to:

**step 1**:  `gdalwarp -srcnodata 0 -dstalpha -of GTiff foo1 foo2`

I am working with Landsat8 band (where no data=0) and when using the `-dstnodata` function I get:

**band1** with *no data* = 'no data' 
**band2** (Alpha band) = '255' for the entire scene/extent

whereas with `-srcnodata`function I get:

**band1** with *no data* = 'no data' 
**band2** (alpha band) with no data = 'no data' and valid data = '255' which then allows to extract polygon for valid data only.

I couldn't fully understand the reason behind this behavior (how alpha is computed?) , but I hope this might help others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

I used `gdal_translate` as [suggested](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2015-October/042857.html) by the GDAL project.

```
gdal_translate -b mask -of vrt -a_nodata 0 test.tif test.vrt
# Note the  -a_nodata 0 doesn't seem to work when the mask is input, so do another pass
gdal_translate -b 1 -of vrt -a_nodata 0 test.vrt test2.vrt
gdal_polygonize.py -q  -8 test2.vrt -b 1 -f "ESRI Shapefile" testdata.shp
```

[image]

Comment: With GDAL trunk version it is now possible to use gdal_polygonize directly against the source image http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Make-gdal-polygonize-to-support-the-mask-band-tp5294371p5294505.html. Some cleanup is needed for removing the no-data polygons, though.

Answer (score 0):

The Image Boundary stayed obsolete.
You can use the Footprint plugin.
http://pt.slideshare.net/LuizMotta3/qgis-ibama-imagefootprint

Comment: This plugin doesn't work anymore.

Comment: The Footprint plugin migrated to Processing Tools.
Now "footprint" is a tool.
Install the "IBAMA processing" plugin, for add this tool.
The plugin run fot LTS version(3.16.x)