# How to extract the boundary of a raster image?

Tags: qgis, raster, landsat-8

I am working in QGIS 2.10.1 and I have the following situation: I have some Landsat8 scenes (different paths and rows) and I want to extract their boundary. My final objective is to superimpose them to the vector of my study area, so that I can show how the scenes cover the study area and in which points they overlap. 
I have already tried to convert the raster into a vector, but QGIS cannot make it, it crashes or it gives me back only part of the polygon.

Is there anybody who's got an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: What workflows are you using to accomplish this? And, if you receive an error, please post the error text in your question.

Comment: At first I was using a stack of raster layers, then I got an error saying that the maximum threshold of 2 GB had been exceeded, so now I am using only one Landsat8 band. I load the band in QGIS, then go to Raster -> Conversion -> Polygonise; I use the raster image as input and then run the tool. However, the output is not a vector covering the area of the raster, but only part of it. In addition to this, I think the result is not a polygon but a polyline, so QGIS has also got difficulties in loading it after creating it...

Comment: Sounds like image footprint extraction? https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/imagefootprint_plugin/

Comment: Perhaps you can find an answer from here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61512/calculating-image-boundary-footprint-of-satellite-images-using-open-source-too

Comment: I get again this error message (sometimes it shows up, other times everything just crashes):
Warning 1: 2GB file size limit reached for E:/Thesis Imagery/Muzza panchromatic\prova_5.shp. Going on, but might cause compatibility issues with third party software 
ERROR 1: Failed to write shape object. File size cannot reach 4294967248 + 136. 

So, apparently the problem is the raster size, but I am using the smaller raster I have got available

Comment: @Mapperz I cannot find this plugin in the plugin list...is it a plugin running with later versions of QGIS?

Comment: Perhaps try using the **Raster Calculator** with an expression like `"raster@1" = 1`. This makes all cells with a value of 1 which might make it easier for QGIS to polygonize...

Comment: @Joseph thank you for your suggestion, maybe it's an easy but good one! I will try it as soon as possible :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Plugin: Image Footprint](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/imagefootprint_plugin/) as commented by @Mapperz. You need to download the plugin from plugin Manager, and this is how it works:

[image]

1. Specify the folder (directory) where the images are located
2. Use `Valid pixels` and specify the CRS of the image.
3. The outpout will create a virtual vector file with a CRS of WGS84 as the default CRS
4. You need to `Save as` the virtual vector file into a permanent file with the correct CRS that should be same as the image file.

Here is the input image file stored in the folder:

[image]

Here is the output footprint:

[image]

You can refer to the presentation: [Qgis ibama imagefootprint](https://pt.slideshare.net/LuizMotta3/qgis-ibama-imagefootprint) for more information.

Comment: This plugin is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Create layer from extent" processing algorithm selecting the desired raster layer as extent source

[image]

Comment: How to get this window in QGIS 3?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an alpha channel in you image, you can use GDAL. to be more specific `gdal_polygonize.py` and use the alpha band to convert to polygon

```
gdal_polygonize.py image.tif "boundary.shp" -b 4 -f "ESRI Shapefile" None DN
```

It will return a polygon layer which has two features in it. inside and outside of alpha band. delete the outside and you have an image boundary.
[GDAL Polygonize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html)