# Extracting raster outline to a vector geometry

Tags: python, rasterio, vectorization, outline

I have a raster data set with an irregular outline (every value outside is NaN) in Python (loaded from `rasterio v.1.3a3` ):

[image]

I'd like to extract its outline to a vector shape, such as a Shapely geometry or a WKT/WKB string (red in the figure below) so that, if I use that shape to clip the larger original region which is entirely containing the raster here above, I will end up on the exact same raster data set.

[image]

Is there a smarter and more direct way than extracting all the indices of the NaN values to a `numpy` array (but, hmm, this would be a bunch of useless data as only the ones 'at the border of where the values are' are of interest), figuring a way to apply the affine transform from the raster metadata to that numpy array (how? I can't find a natural way to do so here: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.transform.html), and finally converting this to a shape so that's it's correctly georeferenced?

I was also thinking using OpenCV but this would probably be overkill...

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/216797/57277

Comment: @NathanThomas : would it be possible to stay inside a Python environment? The raster only exists as a numpy array, if I can avoid file system I/O it could be nice.

Comment: There are GDAL python bindings so you should technically be able to run the same commands but via the api: https://gdal.org/python/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`rasterio.features.dataset_features`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.dataset_features)

```py
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.features import dataset_features
import geopandas as gpd

with rio.open(raster_path) as ds:
    shapes = list(dataset_features(ds, bidx=1, as_mask=True, geographic=False, band=False))

    for shape in shapes:
        print(shape['geometry'])

#Or as a GeoDataFrame
with rio.open(raster_path) as ds:
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(dataset_features(ds, bidx=1, as_mask=True, geographic=False, band=False))
    gdf.to_file(output_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer,  unfortunately, the `vector.geojson` file that was generated this way is not recognized as valid when I try to load it into QGIS for example. Would it be possible to keep it in memory, e.g. as a Shapely geometry or a WKT string, or a dict (JSON-like structure) in order to, see what's happening within the Python console itself, prior to saving it to the disk, or better, to a PostGIS database?

Comment: Yes, just access the `shapes`. Each of the shape elements is a GeoJSON feature.

Comment: Did this solve your question, @swiss_knight? If so, please mark it as solution :)

Comment: No, actually, it does not really answer the question. First because of what I said in a previous comment: "*the raster only exists as a `numpy` array, if I can avoid file system I/O it could be nice.*" and then because the output is not a vector object but a for loop on a list that prints some dictionaries whereas I really need a vector object. I ended up using a solution based on GeoPandas that works very well. If I find the time to post it here... I will.

Comment: Actually, it does answer your question as written. You then commented that you wanted to keep the vector objects in memory, so I edited my answer to show you how to do that, i.e accessing the features/shapes. If you want a geodataframe, just put the features into one, see edit. Nowhere in your question does it specify the raster "only exists as a numpy array". In fact you actually say that "I have a raster data set" which is not a numpy array. Comments are not for adding additional information to your question.