# The term for determining the pixels of a raster image

Tags: raster, terminology

I am looking for an **english well-established term** for determining:

1) invalid/nodata raster image pixels (№ 1 - black ones on the image below) and

2) valid/data raster image pixels (№ 2 - other ones on the image below)

In example:

1 - is "nodata area"

2 - is "raster's body".

[image]

Comment: You've pretty much got the terminology.  NoData is the correct term.

Comment: @MappaGnosis Is "NoData" well-established term? And what about zone № 2?

Comment: "Region of interest" could suit with the YesData area but that term can also mean a more interesting area within valid image data. INSPIRE documents seem to call the net data area as "footprint" http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/file/1539/download?token=7AVgFWtL. NoData feels good to me. Another term I have seen is "offsite" which is known at least to MapServer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

As mentioned in [@user30184's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184) comment in official paper "[INSPIRE data specification on Orthoimagery – Technical Guidelines](http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/file/1539/download?token=7AVgFWtL)" these areas named as follows:

Area № 1 plus area № 2 - is **bounding box**.

Area № 1 - is **no data values**.

Area № 2 - is **footprint**.

Quote from page 129:

> Conversely, the value 0 means that the corresponding pixel in the
>   image holds a no data value (e.g. unknown, withheld). Typically, it
>   must be made transparent when displaying the image.

Picture at page 32:
[image]