# Reading Sentinel-2 L2A product footprint (valid data) from metadata as shapely polygon?

Tags: python, shapely, sentinel-2

Is the valid data footprint of Sentinel-2 products stored somewhere in the SAFE products metadata and if yes, how do I read it and convert it to a `shapely.geometry.Polygon` object in python?

EDIT: by valid data I mean the portion of the frame that is not 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering first part of the question - yes, there is raster footprint in `MTD_MSIL1C.xml` (or `MTD_MSIL2A.xml` for `L2A` products) metadata file. See `<Global_Footprint>` tag. The first value is `Y` coordinate and the second is `X`.

Picture 1:

[image]

Picture 2:

[image]

Answering second part of the question - yes, you could convert it easily. I recommend that you start by reading this [documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#polygons).

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
polygon.area  # equals 0.5 
polygon.length  # equals  3.4142135623730949
```

You may also be interested in reading this question: [The term for determining the pixels of a raster image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269671/the-term-for-determining-the-pixels-of-a-raster-image).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Adding the snippet I wrote to parse the xml and build the polygon in case someone ends up here:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

# product_path is the path to the .SAFE folder
fname = os.path.join(product_path, 'MTD_MSIL2A.xml')
root = ET.parse(fname).getroot()

text = root[1][0][0][0][0].text.strip().split()
coords = [(float(text[i]), float(text[i + 1])) for i in range(0, len(text) - 1, 2)]
geom = Polygon(coords)
```

Comment: appreciate that you added your code to get the footprint from the xml