# How to Polygonize the entire Raster image in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, vector

QGIS is trying to create a polygon for the Raster image using Polygonize (Raster -> Vector).

My Raster Data is a satellite image, but when I Polygonize it, polygon is generated in each pixel and appears in grid form. This problem takes a lot of time to process.
I'm going to create a polygon that fits the overall image size.
Give me a tip.

Comment: Do you want the result to be a `footprint` or `bounding box`? See explanations here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/269689/35561

Comment: By the comment that you wrote into the answer, footprint is what you would like to get. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Extract Layer Extent](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/layertools.html#extract-layer-extent) tool from the processing toolbox:

[image]

The output will be as expected:

[image]

Comment: Hello
I solved the problem by looking at your answer.

Thank you so much.

However, I have a few more questions and leave a comment.

I cut the raster image and created a raster image in the shape of a staircase rather than a square shape.

I used 'Extract Layer Extent' with this, but a square polygon was created. 

Can you make a polygon along the outer line of the cell?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it as a new question with illustrations to make everything clear as per [gis.stackexchange policy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). You have got a square polygon because raster images are composed of pixels and they are always square-shaped or rectangular-shaped.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.

I posted a new question. If you can help me,

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426729/how-do-i-get-the-overlap-area-of-raster-and-vector-to-polygon-in-qgis

Please reply.
Thank you.