# Get difference between raster an its extent

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, vector

I removed the Nodata portion of the landsat8 satellite image using QGIS.
Then, I used the Extract Layer Extent tool to generate polygons along the edges of the cut images.
[image]
[image]

However, the result came out like this.

[image]

The result I want is to make a polygon along the outer edge of the pixel.
Like the picture below.

[image]

Using "polyponize" creates one grid per pixel, which slows down the processing speed considerably. Also, you don't need a grid per pixel.

I have to make a polygon along the end of the pixel, what should I do?

How can I cut the area where the pink square polygon overlaps the satellite image?

Comment: You can use raster calculator with an expression that evaluates true for every pixel. Perhaps`raster@1 > 0`. Then polygonize the result. The cells will be dissolved into a single polygon.

Comment: GDAL utility nearblack may help you and this program is specially made for that purpose https://github.com/gina-alaska/dans-gdal-scripts/blob/master/src/gdal_trace_outline.cc.

Comment: @Matt
Wow! Thank you so much. I've been wandering for days, and all the problems have been solved thanks to you.