# Creating mask layer from raster

Tags: qgis, raster, vector

I have a raster image and I want to get a georeferenced mask layer based on the area of the raster.
For example my raster data:
[image]

I want such a layer.
How can I do this with QGIS? I know about Polygonize but it seems to be time-consuming and has a lot of vectors in it.

Or if it is possible through gdal,rasterio is also fine.
[image]

Comment: You are looking for a way to make a raster footprint. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269671/the-term-for-determining-the-pixels-of-a-raster-image This is well know problem. Try to search for an answer at gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Before using the `Polygonize' tool, reclassify the data (convert it to a binary image) - this will speed up processing.

Comment: This thread might be of help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/457840/use-raster-layer-as-a-mask-over-a-polygon-in-qgis

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases like in your example the GDAL nearblack tool can do the job https://gdal.org/programs/nearblack.html

It is possible to set either an alpha band or a dedicated mask band with the tool. The tools is scanning the image row by row from left to right and right to left and does usually pretty good job. However, if the nodata areas in the image has very special shape (concave enclosures) they may not be captured correctly.

Comment: I did not get your answer. Why I should Convert nearly black/white borders to black? I need a simple vector layer which is same as raster.

Comment: Ok, you did not say that you want vectors. In that case you must continue and convert the the alpha/mask band into a polygon with https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html.