# Use Raster Layer as a Mask over a polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, line, masking

I have a raster layer, as seen on the attached image, that works as a background of my working area. The red line, that marks the limit between the two countries, is a .shp file that, naturally, goes beyond the area of interest, the aforementioned raster.

What I am trying to achieve is a way of displaying the red line *only* when it overlays the raster, not outside it.

Using *Clip* or *Intersect* inside the Vector - Geoprocessing Tools menu don't work here, as they only work *Vector on Vector*; I tried creating a *Scratch layer* with a polygon of the same shape as the raster. In this way, I can clip the border line, but it creates, naturally, a new line around the raster.
[image]

Is there a way to mask the red line as desired? Alternatively, is there a way to *"cut"* the polygon in two parts, by making two cuts (something similar as what the *Scissors* tool does in Illustrator) and just deleting the unneeded line?

**Edit:** This is the outcome using the method in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/457850/183135) reply, which is the same outcome as using *Clip* or *Intersect*:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R11zD.jpg

The reason behind that, methinks, is that the border line marked in red is a closed polygon. See here:
[image]

With this update, any further solution comes to mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer by @Cushen, but with two improvements:

1. Avoid the problem of the outline along the raster's borders. It seems your vector layer is a polygon, not line. So you need the intersection of the **boundary of the polygon** with the raster, not of the polygon itself. use [`boundary()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#boundary) function for that.
2. Needs not auxiliary layer. You can get the extent of the raster layer automatically with the function [`layer_property()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#layer-property).

Like this, you can do it all at once with geometry generator, using this expression (replace `raster_layer` with the name of your raster layer and be sure to set Geometry generator's Geomtry type to `LineString`):

```
intersection( 
    boundary($geometry),  
    layer_property ('raster_layer', 'extent')
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a really elegant solution indeed. However, in my case, it tries to close the polygon anyway, resulting on this shape: https://imgur.com/5dAF46z

Comment: Can you provide sample data for testing?

Comment: Edit: I managed to make it work. I just had to change the Geometry Type from Polygon to Line on the .shp layer.

Comment: Nice, had a look but didn't know about " layer_property ('raster_layer', 'extent') "

Answer (score 5):

We can use the *Scratch Layer* polygon which has the same shape as the raster inside geometry generator for the line as follows:
My *Scratch Layer* here is called **Extent**. This layer can remain unrendered/invisible.

```
  intersection( $geometry, geometry( get_feature_by_id('Extent',1)))
```

[image: Geometry Generator]

Example:
[image: Example Picture]

Comment: By using the Geometry Generator in this way, I get the same result as with the Clip tool. See here: https://imgur.com/BUngFuA

Comment: Apply a (very) small, negative buffer around the extent layer so that the rectancular boundary line is hidden. Disadvantage is that the border does not exactly reach until the border of the raster

Comment: As I commented on the answer below, I managed to make it work just by changing the Geometry Type from Polygon to Line on the .shp layer. I accepted the second answer instead of this one just because it doesn't require the extra step of creating the Scratch Layer, but just for the record, this works like a charm, too.

Answer (score 3):

The best way (fastest, no extra data or expressions, done purely in the graphical rendering step) would be to group the two layers, render them as group and let the raster mask the line. Here is an example:

[image]

Add both layers to a group and set the group to "Render Layers as Group":
[image]

Have the line layer on top of the raster layer and set its rendering mode to "Paint Inside Below":

[image]

Comment: Great idea, didn't know about that, +1. However, OP has not a line, but a polygon layer and with this, it will not work without extra expressions.

Comment: Are you sure? It should work the same.

Comment: Seems you're right - only thing to be aware of is that the Fill style has to be changed to `No Brush` and the rendering mode is deactivated if the layer's visibility is turned off and on again. Not sure if this might be a bug.